# REGEXP in CASE Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

```
SELECT title,
CASE WHEN title REGEXP '[0-9]' THEN CONCAT(sid,'X',gid,'X',parent_qid,'#',title)
ELSE CONCAT( sid, 'X', gid, 'X',parent_qid ,title) END AS survey_title
FROM `lime_questions`
WHERE question like '%Vision%'
```

Can any one correct me If am wrong with my above case statement. My intention is when title from my table is having only Numeric then i would like to concatenate as shown in my Query. But my sql code is not concatenating as it was written above when my regexp is not matching too. Please correct me.

```
Result Set:

title    survey_title
8      21712X102X4180#8
MM08   83628X37X1742#MM08

Expected Output:

title    survey_title
8      21712X102X4180#8
MM08   83628X37X1742MM08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT title,
CASE WHEN title REGEXP 'ˆ[0-9]+$' THEN CONCAT(sid,'X',gid,'X',parent_qid,'#',title)
ELSE CONCAT( sid, 'X', gid, 'X',parent_qid ,title) END AS survey_title
FROM `lime_questions`
WHERE question like '%Vision%'
```

Comment: What output do you get? the same as before?

Comment: Yeah it was like that, but now it is working on sudden... I dont know the reason, Anyways thanks :) @Ashalynd